# Illegal Break Statement. NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

While Executing the below code. it shows illegal break statement error. I am new to nodejs kindly help me to resolve this.

Code Is:

```
describe('Locating elements using JS', function () {
            it('Locate H1 tags', function () {
                browser.get("http://angularjs.org");
                element.all(by.js(function () {
                    //This is javascript code which will get h1 elements
                    var elementsArray = new Array();
                    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
                    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
                        if (anchors[i].textContent != '') {
                            elementsArray.push(anchors[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return elementsArray;
                })).then(function (webElements) {
                    //prints Number of h1 tags identified
                    console.log(webElements.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < webElements.length; i++) {
                        webElements[i].getText().then(function (text) {
                            //prints text of each H1 tag
                            console.log(text);
                            //Verifying the text of each h1 tag should not be empty
                            expect(text).not.toBe('');
                            if(text=="Directives"){
                                break;
                            }

                        })
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: yep, you have a break inside a callback function - looks like it's inside a loop, but it isn't

Comment: if I understand the code, you want to terminate the loop early, from within an asynchronous callback - that's going to be difficult, since there's no guarantee in which order the `.then`  in `webElements[i].getText().then(function (text) {` will get called ... unless you require the `webElements[i].getText()` to run in series (i.e. wait for previous one to complete before starting the next one)

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is using callback chain as loop will be long over before any async process completes

Comment: possible code https://jsfiddle.net/xevhbr9j/

Comment: @Venugopal P .. Did you try the below answer... Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using a `break` NOT directly inside a for/while - but inside a promise resolution function which is incorrect.

By the way as a side note if you are trying to filter one `element` out of `elementArray` Protractor API provides a beautiful method - [ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) which does the exact job for you.

> Apply a filter function to each element within the ElementArrayFinder.
>   Returns a new ElementArrayFinder with all elements that pass the
>   filter function. The filter function receives the ElementFinder as the
>   first argument and the index as a second arg. This does not actually
>   retrieve the underlying list of elements, so it can be used in page
>   objects.

```
describe('Locating elements using JS', function () {
    it('Locate H1 tags', function () {
        browser.get("http://angularjs.org");
        element.all(by.js(function () {
            //Your existing JS Code to identify elements
        })).filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
                return text === 'Directives';
            });
        }).first().click()
    });
});
```

BTW In case you want to checkout more ways to play around with elements inside an `elementArray` like each,map,reduce so on .. check [this link](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)